# Neo4J 2.x with Rexster

Tags: neo4j, rexster

I'm wondering if anyone has successfully configured Rexster-server to work Neo4j-2.0.1-HA? I read a few threads regarding comparability but never found a good solution.

I have pulled the latest rexster source (2.5.0-SNAPSHOT) from master and built it. After configuration of both Neo4j2.0.1 and rexster I get the following error trying to launch rexster.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.GraphDatabaseAPI.getNodeManager()Lorg/neo4j/kernel/impl/core/NodeManager;

Rexster config is as follows.

```
<graph>
            <graph-enabled>true</graph-enabled>
            <graph-name>KooboodleGraph</graph-name>
            <graph-type>neo4jgraph</graph-type>
            <graph-location>/mnt/neo4j/data/graph.db</graph-location>
            <!-- <graph-location>http://x.x.x.x:7474/db/data</graph-location> -->
        <graph-high-availability>true</graph-high-availability>
            <extensions>
                <allows>
                    <allow>tp:gremlin</allow>
                    <allow>zeus-v1:*</allow>
                </allows>
            </extensions>
        <properties>
            <neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory>285M</neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory>
                <neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory>285M</neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory>
                <neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory>100M</neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory>
                <neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory>100M</neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory>
                <neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory>10M</neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory>
                <neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory>10M</neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory>
                <neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory>10M</neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory>
            <ha.machine_id>1</ha.machine_id>
                <ha.server>x.x.x.x:6001</ha.server>
            <ha.cluster_server>x.x.x.x:5001-5099</ha.cluster_server>
                <ha.initial_hosts>x.x.x.x:5001,x.x.x.x:5001</ha.initial_hosts>
        </properties>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j-ha</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j-management</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>   
        </graph>
```

Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreaciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please always share the full stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Rexter is relying on non-public API of Neo4j. Since a lot of internals of Neo4j have changed from 1.x -> 2.x my guess is that Rexter has not followed up on these changes. E.g. `GraphDatabaseAPI` is part of non-public API.

Neo4j's public API is documented at http://api.neo4j.org/.

To solve this Rexter's codebase needs to be patched appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this new branch in Rexster dedicated to Neo4j2:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/tree/neo4j2

Rexster doesn't directly reference Neo4j APIs in any way (it operates solely over Blueprints), but there are a number of naming conflicts and things that occur given the way things are set up in the master branch.  I'm not completely sure how TinkerPop will end up releasing Rexster support for Neo4j2...some thought there will be needed, but at least until then it is possible to build that branch to start playing around.

Answer (score 0):

Rexster config is ha.machine_id but Neo4j HA config is ha.server_id, then Rexster+Neo4j2 then rexster.xml include both of them.